# how should I combine these regex?

Tags: regex, perl

```
 $syb =~ s/(at{3,6})/\U$1/gi;

 $syb =~ s/(aat{2,5})/\U$1/gi;

 $syb =~ s/(aaat{1,4})/\U$1/gi;

 $syb =~ s/(aaaat{0,3})/\U$1/gi;

 $syb =~ s/(aaaaat{0,2})/\U$1/gi;

 $syb =~ s/(a{4,7})/\U$1/gi;

 $syb =~ s/(aaaaaat)/\U$1/gi;

 $syb =~ s/(t{4,7})/\U$1/gi;
```

Is there any way I could get all these regexps into one? Is it bad practice to use this many regexps on the same string? the end result should if $syb is `aaatcgacgatcgatcaatttcgaaaaaggattttttatgcacgcacggggattaaaa` 
the regexp should make it
`AAATcgacgatcgatcAATTTcgAAAAAggATTTTTTatgcacgcacggggattAAAA`

one problem with my regexps is that they match `aaaatttt` as two separate matches and output `AAAATTTT`. i need to fix this as well.

i have a string of A's C's T's and G's stored in $syb. i want to capitalize any part of the string that has a set of A's followed by T's, just A's or just T's (T's followed by A's should not) and the capitalized section may be no shorter than 4 and no longer than 7

Comment: The plural is "regular expressions" with an S :-p "Regex" isn't a word anyway, so "regexes" or whatever you want is fine.

Comment: I suppose that some more context might be needed.  What exactly are you trying to do?  A regex might not be the best option, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: I generally say "regexps" as the plural. I tend to refer to the language as a whole as "regex" and an individual expression as a "regexp".

Comment: i have a string of A's C's T's and G's stored in $syb. i want to capitalize any part of the string that has a set of A's followed by T's, just A's or just T's (T's followed by A's should not) and the capitalized section may be no shorter than 4 and no longer than 7.

Comment: At the very end of your test string, ATT and AAAA are back-to-back separate matches. What then?

Comment: att is shorter than 4 and therefor should be ignored on the subject of back to back matches this would count as two AATTAAAT because it breaks at TA, however AAAATTTT would not because it is longer than 7 without breaking.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Sorry, you're right, it's 3 not 4.

Comment: AAAATTTT could match AAAA followed by TTTT.

Comment: yes which is one of the problems with the way i have it now.

Comment: @Wiseguy let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1325/discussion-between-orion-and-wiseguy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a tough one. I think this might work:

```
s/((?<!a)a|(?<!a|t)t)((?<!t)\1|t){3,6}(?!\2|t)/\U$&/gi
```

Essentially, what I'm doing is:

1. Get an `a` not preceded by an `a`. Or a `t` not preceded by an `a` or `t`.

   - `((?<!a)a|(?<!a|t)t)`
2. Get 3-6 more of the first match, or `t's` not preceded by a `t`

   - `((?<!t)\1|t){3,6}`
3. Make sure it is not followed by the last item in the sequence or a `t`.

   - `(?!\2|t)/`

And the perl code:

```
$syb = "aaatcgacgatcgatcaatttcgaaaaaggattttttatgcacgcacggggattaaaaactgaaaattttactgaaaaaaaasttttttts";
$syb =~ s/((?<!a)a|(?<!a|t)t)((?<!t)\1|t){3,6}(?!\2|t)/\U$&/gi;
print $syb;
```

---

**Edit** taking a queue from qtax I've removed capturing groups from mine and chars from his:

```
s/(?:(?<!a)a|(?<!a|t)t)(?:(?<!t)a|t){3,6}(?!(?<=a)a|t)/\U$&/gi
```

**Edit:** reducing the regex by 5 chars.

```
s/(?<!a|t(?=t))(?:a|t(?!a)){3,6}(?:a(?!a)|t)(?!t)/\U$&/gi
```

with commments

```
s/
# Look behind for a char not an 'a' nor a 't' followed by a 't'
(?<!a|t(?=t))
# Capture 3-6 'a's or 't's not followed by 'a's
(?:a|t(?!a)){3,6}
# Capture an 'a' not followed by an 'a', or a 't'
(?:a(?!a)|t)
#make sure none of this is followed by a 't'.
(?!t)
/\U$&/gix;
```

Comment: It won't match the 7 t's in `tttttttt`

Comment: Unless Perl v5.10.0 doesn't support it, your regex doesn't recognize `ttttttttt...`. Please just write the complete Perl program. (Also, show that the replacement is `\U$&` instead of `\U$1`.)

Comment: @KennyTM By my understanding, it's not supposed to match `ttttttttt` at all (even part of it), so it's working as desired.

Comment: @Kenny That's right, the regexp isn't supposed to match 8 t's. But if you put just 7 t's, then it will work. http://codepad.org/r8pip50U

Comment: @Wiseguy: The last regex provided by OP is `$syb =~ s/(t{4,7})/\U$1/gi;`.

Comment: @Jacob: No it should match 7 of the 8 t's and transform to TTTTTTTt. That's my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the chat, if the possible combination is longer than 7 it should be ignored, and no parts of it replaced. [See this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/992828#992828).

My back reference free solution:

```
s/
(?:(?<!a)a|(?<!t|a)t)
(?:(?<=a)a|(?<=a)t|(?<=t)t){3,6}
(?!(?<=a)a|(?<=a)t|(?<=t)t)
/\U$&/gix;
```

With some comments:

```
s/
# match the first [at] only if not part of a valid sequence
(?:(?<!a)a|(?<!t|a)t)
# only match the allowed transitions: a->a, a->t, t->t
(?:(?<=a)a|(?<=a)t|(?<=t)t){3,6}
# ending can not be a valid transition: negate the above
(?!(?<=a)a|(?<=a)t|(?<=t)t)
/\U$&/gix;
```

**Update:** Applied the shortening ideas by Jacob, here with some comments:

```
s/
# match the first a or t only if it's not part of a valid sequence
(?:(?<!a)a|(?<!t|a)t)
# only match the allowed transitions: a->a, a->t, t->t
# (t can follow any of the previous chars, so no need to check it)
(?:(?<=a)a|t){3,6}
# ending can not be a valid transition: negate the above
(?!(?<=a)a|t)
/\U$&/gix;
```

---

**Edit**: A less regexy solution just for fun:

```
s/(a+t*|t+)/(length $1 >= 4 && length $1 <= 7)? "\U$1": $1/gie;
```

*PS: Thanks to the OP for a more fun than usual regex question. :)*

Comment: Unfortunately, it matches `aaaatttt` http://codepad.org/KwyDtV6h Is there something you can change to get it working?

Comment: `(?:(?<=a)(?!a)|(?<=t)(?!t))` -> `(?:(?<=a)(?!a|t)|(?<=t)(?!t))` fixes it. Pretty good.

Comment: Even better fix `(?:(?<=a)(?!a)|(?<=t)(?!t))` -> `(?!(?<=a)a|(?<=a)t|(?<=t)t)`.